# Как реализовать переход между фрагментами с разными контейнерами?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В activity_main есть два контейнера для фрагментов (у них разные размеры). Как реализовать переход с одного фрагмента (контейнер1) на фрагмента второго контейнера? (контейнер1 в content_main, а контейнер2 в content_main2)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.testapp147.MainActivity">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/BottomNavMain"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/BottomNavMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_menu_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottomnavigation">
        </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_fab_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

При установке слушателя на кнопку перехода между фрагментами выходит ошибка NPE. Что делать?

```
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment someFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame2, someFragment );
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Не понятно, что вы имеете в виду под `реализовать переход с одного фрагмента на фрагмента второго контейнера`. Какая-то анимация должна произойти или вам надо данные передать?..

Comment: Предыдущая версия вашего комментария была понятна. Теперь опять ничего не понятно. Вы просто повторили текст вопроса(

Answer (score 0):

Можно по разному. Вот варианты по возрастанию правильности и сложности реализации:

1. Сделайте метод в активити, открывающий нужный фрагмент. В другом фрагменте получите активити `getActivity()` и скастуйте её к типу вашей активити `MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();` теперь вы можете просто вызвать метод активити, который и добавит фрагмент в неё `activity.addMyFragment();`
2. Тоже самое, но кастовать надо к интерфейсу, коий актиивти реализует. Интерфейс будет содержать метод `void addMyFragment();`
3. Использовать библиотеку/фреймворк для навигации. Например [Cicerone](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone). Как ей пользоваться - читайте по ссылке.